# Read only specific files in MultiResourceItemReader in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I got a requirement to read multiple files in a folder using spring batch. I am able to do it with MultiResourceItemReader but I need to read only specific files in the folder. We SFTP to client server, transfer files to our local folder, and decrypt those files in the same folder and then read those files. These files might end with different extensions like xxx.confirmation.csvtxt, xxx.csv.pgp(encrypted), xxx.error(error files), xxx.csv(decrypted files). I am  supposed to read all .csv and .error files only. Our batch runs for every 3hrs, In initial step we connect to server and transfer files and store those file names in job context to pass to next step, How can i read only these files in MultiResourceItemReader? I tried to get from saveStepExecution method and set it in setResource() method but seems like setResource method is called before saveStepExecution. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show us your configuration for MultiResourceItemReader?

Comment: Do you intend to have something like this: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?134355-How-to-define-a-pattern-for-multiple-filetypes-as-MultiResourceItemReader-property ?

Comment: The default Ant style pattern matching won't work for this. Simplest way is probably to perform exclusions in the ItemReader.